# Stuck at grub. Keyboard won't work

Tags: grub2, keyboard

After a power outage, Ubuntu got stuck at Grub. But for some reason my keyboard won't work. I cannot even get to the bios. My keyboard does not receive any power! (It does work properly after booting to the OS however)

Things I've tried:

- Resetting the bios (jumper + battery method)
- Plugging keyboard into different USB ports (tried all of them)
- new USB keyboard

Things I plan on trying:

- Try to access the bios using a ps2 keyboard

I have now solved the issue by putting the hard drive into another PC, reinstalling Ubuntu then putting the drive back to where it is meant to be. The keyboard works fine when in Ubuntu but not when booting!

Any ideas on how to get my keyboard to work before booting into Ubuntu?

actually setting a timeout to the Grub page that appears after an improper shut down would suffice. How can I do that?

P.S: my motherboard is Intel D954CGNL

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Ubuntu, and run:

```
$ sudo -i
# grub-install /dev/sda
# update-grub
```

This should reset GRUB.